# Asynchronous method exception: Invalid attempt to call CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await, entity-framework-core

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'DBR.Web.Context.DBRContext'.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckDataIsReady(Int32 columnIndex, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn, Boolean permitAsync, String methodName)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 i)
         at lambda_method340(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SplitQueryResultCoordinator )
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
      System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckDataIsReady(Int32 columnIndex, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn, Boolean permitAsync, String methodName)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 i)
         at lambda_method340(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SplitQueryResultCoordinator )
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
```

This exception occur when I try to go to get an object (GetByIdAsync()-method) in ASP.NET Core application (Blazor Server). It's used on a service, and that service call my EntityFramework Repository that uses the method GetByIdAsync(Guid id).

When I remove the asynchronous part of EFRepository: .ToListAsync() to .ToList(), it starts working with no issues. Does anyone know why? I want to keep them asynchronous somehow.

**My UI:**

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    if (CreateOrEdit is not "rediger" && CreateOrEdit is not "opret")
    {
        errorMessage = "Der er ingenting at se her. :(";
        isInvalidPath = true;

        return;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WorkshopId))
    {
        Func<IQueryable<Workshop>, IIncludableQueryable<Workshop, object>> workshopIncludes = workshop => workshop.Include(x => x.Address!);

        ResponseDTO<WorkshopDTO> loadedWorkshop = await WorkshopService.GetByIdAsync(Guid.Parse(WorkshopId), isTrackingDisabled: false, includeProperties: workshopIncludes);

        if (loadedWorkshop.Success)
        {
            if (CreateOrEdit is "rediger")
            {
                workshopToEdit = loadedWorkshop.Content!;
            }
            else
            {
                workshopInputModel.Name = loadedWorkshop.Content!.Name;
                workshopInputModel.PhoneNumber = loadedWorkshop.Content!.PhoneNumber;
                workshopInputModel.AddressInputModel!.Street = loadedWorkshop.Content!.Address!.Street;
                workshopInputModel.AddressInputModel!.City = loadedWorkshop.Content!.Address.City;
                workshopInputModel.AddressInputModel!.PostCode = loadedWorkshop.Content!.Address.PostCode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My GetByIdAsync Service:**

```cs
public async Task<ResponseDTO<TOUT>> GetByIdAsync(Guid entityId, bool isTrackingDisabled = true, Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>>? includeProperties = null, Expression<Func<T, T>>? selector = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ResponseDTO<TOUT> responseDTO = await repository.GetByIdAsync(entityId, isTrackingDisabled, includeProperties, selector, cancellationToken);

    return responseDTO;
}
```

**My GetByIdAsync EFRepository:**

```cs
public async Task<ResponseDTO<TOUT>> GetByIdAsync(Guid id, bool isTrackingDisabled = true, Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>>? includeProperties = null, Expression<Func<T, T>>? selector = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    try
    {
        T requestedEntity = (await table.QueryHelper(selector: selector, includeProperties: includeProperties, isTrackingDisabled: isTrackingDisabled).ToListAsync(cancellationToken)).Find(entity => (Guid)entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id")!.GetValue(entity)! == id) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(null);

        TOUT requestedEntityDTO = mapper.Map<TOUT>(requestedEntity);

        return new ResponseDTO<TOUT> { Success = true, Content = requestedEntityDTO };
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
    {
        return new ResponseDTO<TOUT> { Success = false, ErrorMessage = $"Din anmodning blev ikke fundet - prøv igen.", ExceptionMessage = ex.Message, InnerExceptionMessage = ex.InnerException?.Message, ErrorType = ErrorType.EntityNotFound };
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        return new ResponseDTO<TOUT> { Success = false, ErrorMessage = "Din anmodning blev annulleret.", ExceptionMessage = ex.Message, InnerExceptionMessage = ex.InnerException?.Message, ErrorType = ErrorType.CancellationTokenRequested };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new ResponseDTO<TOUT> { Success = false, ErrorMessage = "Ubehandlet serverfejl. Kontakt server administrator.", ExceptionMessage = ex.Message, InnerExceptionMessage = ex.InnerException?.Message, ErrorType = ErrorType.Unhandled };
    }
}
```

**My QueryHelper (extension method):**

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> QueryHelper<T>(this DbSet<T> table, bool isTrackingDisabled = true, Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>>? includeProperties = null, Expression<Func<T, bool>>? filter = null, Expression<Func<T, T>>? selector = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>? orderBy = null) where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> query = table.AsSplitQuery();

    if (isTrackingDisabled)
    {
        query = query.AsNoTracking();
    }

    if (filter is not null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (includeProperties is not null)
    {
        query = includeProperties(query);
    }

    if (selector is not null)
    {
        query = query.Select(selector);
    }

    if (orderBy is not null)
    {
        query = orderBy(query);
    }

    return query;
}
```

**My 'Workshop' domain model:**

```cs
public class Workshop : BaseEntity
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(AddressId))]
    public Address? Address { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = null!;

    public ICollection<Member>? Members { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Case>? Cases { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Specialization>? Specializations { get; set; }
}
```

**My 'Address' domain model:**

```cs
public class Address : BaseEntity
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Street { get; set; } = null!;

    [StringLength(25)]
    public string City { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    public short? PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

**My DBRContext in Program.cs:**

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBRContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBRContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connectionstring 'DBRContext' was not found."), options => options.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery)));
```

Comment: Usually it is a sign that something is not properly awaited somewhere. Though based on provided code it is not obvious where and what.

Comment: I let out some code parts out to be more user friendly for you guys, should I always provide full code?

Comment: Ideally you should provide a [mre]. Though in quite a lot of cases finding a [mre] solves the question) And there are some cases when it is very hard to post one here and somebody still will be able to help you even having parts of it. But still - having [mre] vastly improves chances for your question being answered and you having some upvotes for it)

Comment: I have updated the post and provided everything, I think is necessary to reproduce the issue

Comment: If your query from the database returns no data than there is nothing to enumerate and you will get an exception.   You should query and then test to make sure query is not null before trying to extract the data.

Comment: It is not null, and data is returned from Get Workshop details, and navigating to Edit Workshop details causes exception. Though, both make use of the GetByIdAsync in my repository.

Comment: Where is the instance of `DBR.Web.Context.DBRContext` being created and disposed?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Post updated to include it, it's in my Program.cs where it's dependency injected and constructor injected in my EFRepository to be used.

Comment: 'table' in EFRepository as you see in my post is assigned to be table = context.Set<T>();